# "Guest-specific operations were attempted on a machine that is not ready for guest communication." exception when provisioning an AWS EC2 machine

Tags: amazon-ec2, vagrant, amazon-web-services

I have used `vagrant up` to create a AWS EC2 instance.

After I have stopped and restarted this instance, I want to rerun `vagrant provision` with updated provision clauses in the `Vagrantfile`. It failed with this error message:

```
Guest-specific operations were attempted on a machine that is not
ready for guest communication. This should not happen and a bug
should be reported.
```

If I use ssh to connect to the instance I can login without any problem. The ssh private key file is exactly the same one as specified in the Vagrantfile.

**Why it fails?**

The error message leads to a [bug report](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2251) in vagrant GitHub project but it is about the vagrant-vbguest plugin.

Here is the print out from `vagrant provision --debug`. (Some lines are replaced by ... due SO characters limit)

```
 INFO global: Vagrant version: 1.6.5
 INFO global: Ruby version: 2.0.0
 INFO global: RubyGems version: 2.0.14
 INFO global: VAGRANT_EXECUTABLE="/Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/bin/vagrant"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_INSTALLER_EMBEDDED_DIR="/Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_INSTALLER_VERSION="2"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_DETECTED_OS="Darwin"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_INSTALLER_ENV="1"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_INTERNAL_BUNDLERIZED="1"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_LOG="debug"
 ...
 INFO machine: Calling action: provision on provider AWS (i-99999999)
DEBUG environment: Attempting to acquire process-lock: machine-action-8d4f93c9bedf41af432adedf7b959248
DEBUG environment: Attempting to acquire process-lock: dotlock
 INFO environment: Acquired process lock: dotlock
 INFO environment: Released process lock: dotlock
 INFO environment: Acquired process lock: machine-action-8d4f93c9bedf41af432adedf7b959248
 INFO host: Autodetecting host type for [#<Vagrant::Environment: /Users/antkong/dev/project/aws/vagrant-setup/01-sensu-server>]
DEBUG host: Trying: arch
DEBUG host: Trying: darwin
 INFO host: Detected: darwin!
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 3 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x000001013c96f8>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::EnvSet:0x00000101485330>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Berkshelf::Vagrant::Action::SetUI:0x000001014852e0>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Berkshelf::Vagrant::Action::LoadShelf:0x00000101485290>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Berkshelf::Vagrant::Action::ConfigureChef:0x00000101485240>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::ConfigValidate:0x000001014851f0>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::Call:0x000001014851a0>
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 3 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x000001014d6af0>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::IsCreated:0x000001014dd030>
 INFO machine: Calling action: read_state on provider AWS (i-99999999)
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 2 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x0000010152c5e0>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::ConfigValidate:0x0000010233f9e8>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ConnectAWS:0x0000010233f7e0>
 INFO connect_aws: Connecting to AWS...
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ReadState:0x00000102429458>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ReadState:0x00000102429458>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ConnectAWS:0x0000010233f7e0>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::ConfigValidate:0x0000010233f9e8>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::IsCreated:0x000001014dd030>
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 3 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Warden:0x00000100caa340>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Proc:0x0000010358acd8@/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:94 (lambda)>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::Provision:0x00000100ca9e90>
 INFO provision: Ignoring sentinel check, forcing provision
 INFO provision: Checking provisioner sentinel file...
 INFO provision: Sentinel found! Not provisioning.
 INFO interface: warn: The cookbook path '/Users/antkong/dev/project/aws/vagrant-setup/01-sensu-server/data_bags' doesn't exist. Ignoring...
 INFO interface: warn: ==> default: The cookbook path '/Users/antkong/dev/project/aws/vagrant-setup/01-sensu-server/data_bags' doesn't exist. Ignoring...
==> default: The cookbook path '/Users/antkong/dev/project/aws/vagrant-setup/01-sensu-server/data_bags' doesn't exist. Ignoring...
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::Omnibus::Action::InstallChef:0x00000100df12a8>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Berkshelf::Vagrant::Action::Install:0x000001032c8428>
 INFO interface: info: Updating Vagrant's berkshelf: '/Users/antkong/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20150122-45589-1w257mf-default'
[0mUpdating Vagrant's berkshelf: '/Users/antkong/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20150122-45589-1w257mf-default'[0m
 INFO interface: info: Resolving cookbook dependencies...
[0mResolving cookbook dependencies...[0m
 INFO interface: info: Using apt (2.6.1)
[0mUsing apt (2.6.1)[0m
 INFO interface: info: Using build-essential (2.1.3)
[0mUsing build-essential (2.1.3)[0m
 INFO interface: info: Using chef_handler (1.1.6)
[0mUsing chef_handler (1.1.6)[0m
 INFO interface: info: Using dmg (2.2.2)
[0mUsing dmg (2.2.2)[0m
 INFO interface: info: Using erlang (1.5.6)
[0mUsing erlang (1.5.6)[0m
 INFO interface: info: Using git (4.1.0)
[0mUsing git (4.1.0)[0m
 INFO interface: info: Using postfix (3.6.2)
[0mUsing postfix (3.6.2)[0m
 INFO interface: info: Using python (1.4.6)
[0mUsing python (1.4.6)[0m INFO interface: info: Using rabbitmq (3.8.0)

[0mUsing rabbitmq (3.8.0)[0m INFO interface: info: Using redisio (2.2.4)

[0mUsing redisio (2.2.4)[0m
 INFO interface: info: Using sensu (2.3.0)
 INFO interface: info: Using runit (1.5.14)
[0mUsing runit (1.5.14)[0m
[0mUsing sensu (2.3.0)[0m
 INFO interface: info: Using ulimit (0.3.2)
[0mUsing ulimit (0.3.2)[0m
 INFO interface: info: Using vim (1.1.2)
[0mUsing vim (1.1.2)[0m
 INFO interface: info: Using windows (1.36.1)
[0mUsing windows (1.36.1)[0m
 INFO interface: info: Using yum (3.5.2)
[0mUsing yum (3.5.2)[0m
 INFO interface: info: Using yum-epel (0.6.0)
[0mUsing yum-epel (0.6.0)[0m
 INFO interface: info: Using yum-erlang_solutions (0.2.0)
[0mUsing yum-erlang_solutions (0.2.0)[0m
 INFO interface: info: Vendoring apt (2.6.1) to /Users/antkong/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20150122-45589-1w257mf-default/apt
[0mVendoring apt (2.6.1) to /Users/antkong/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20150122-45589-1w257mf-default/apt[0m
 ...
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Berkshelf::Vagrant::Action::Upload:0x000001032c83d8>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::SyncedFolders:0x000001032c8338>
 INFO synced_folders: Synced Folder Implementation: rsync
 INFO synced_folders:   - /vagrant: . => /vagrant
 INFO synced_folders:   - v-csc-1: /Users/antkong/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20150122-45589-1w257mf-default => /tmp/vagrant-chef-4/chef-solo-1/cookbooks
 INFO synced_folders: Invoking synced folder prepare for: rsync
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Proc:0x0000010344ac88@/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:94 (lambda)>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<Proc:0x0000010344ac88@/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:94 (lambda)>
 INFO synced_folders: Invoking synced folder enable: rsync
DEBUG ssh: Checking whether SSH is ready...
 INFO machine: Calling action: read_ssh_info on provider AWS (i-99999999)
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 2 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x00000108dcfc68>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::ConfigValidate:0x00000108dd4d58>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ConnectAWS:0x00000108dd4d30>
 INFO connect_aws: Connecting to AWS...
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ReadSSHInfo:0x0000010d06b928>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ReadSSHInfo:0x0000010d06b928>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ConnectAWS:0x00000108dd4d30>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::ConfigValidate:0x00000108dd4d58>
DEBUG ssh: Checking key permissions: /Users/antkong/dev/project/aws/ubuntu-aws-ec2-konga.pem
 INFO ssh: Attempting SSH connection...
 INFO ssh: Attempting to connect to SSH...
 INFO ssh:   - Host: 124.188.56.254
 INFO ssh:   - Port: 22
 INFO ssh:   - Username: ubuntu
 INFO ssh:   - Password? false
 INFO ssh:   - Key Path: ["/Users/antkong/dev/project/aws/ubuntu-aws-ec2-konga.pem"]
DEBUG ssh: == Net-SSH connection debug-level log START ==
DEBUG ssh: D, [2015-01-23T16:27:08.281573 #54236] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.session[805accd0]: establishing connection to 124.188.56.254:22
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:08.479204 #54236] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.session[805accd0]: connection established
I, [2015-01-23T16:27:08.479532 #54236]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[805b7810]: negotiating protocol version
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:08.677587 #54236] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[805b7810]: remote is `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2'
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:08.677699 #54236] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[805b7810]: local is `SSH-2.0-Ruby/Net::SSH_2.9.2 universal.x86_64-darwin12.5.0'
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:08.873599 #54236] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[805b08d0]: read 1448 bytes
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:08.873789 #54236] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[805b08d0]: read 184 bytes
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:08.873917 #54236] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[805b08d0]: received packet nr 0 type 20 len 1628
I, [2015-01-23T16:27:08.874086 #54236]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[811fc5a8]: got KEXINIT from server
I, [2015-01-23T16:27:08.874427 #54236]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[811fc5a8]: sending KEXINIT
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:08.874782 #54236] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[805b08d0]: queueing packet nr 0 type 20 len 1684
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:08.874918 #54236] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[805b08d0]: sent 1688 bytes
I, [2015-01-23T16:27:08.874975 #54236]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[811fc5a8]: negotiating algorithms
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:08.875220 #54236] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[811fc5a8]: negotiated:
* kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
* host_key: ssh-rsa
* encryption_server: aes128-cbc
* encryption_client: aes128-cbc
* hmac_client: hmac-sha1
* hmac_server: hmac-sha1
* compression_client: none
* compression_server: none
* language_client: 
* language_server: 
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:08.875261 #54236] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[811fc5a8]: exchanging keys
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:08.875562 #54236] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[805b08d0]: queueing packet nr 1 type 34 len 20
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:08.875626 #54236] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[805b08d0]: sent 24 bytes
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:09.267990 #54236] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[805b08d0]: read 152 bytes
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:09.268156 #54236] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[805b08d0]: received packet nr 1 type 31 len 148
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:09.269854 #54236] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[805b08d0]: queueing packet nr 2 type 32 len 140
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:09.269930 #54236] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[805b08d0]: sent 144 bytes
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:09.463176 #54236] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[805b08d0]: read 720 bytes
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:09.463390 #54236] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[805b08d0]: received packet nr 2 type 33 len 700
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:09.465374 #54236] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[805b08d0]: queueing packet nr 3 type 21 len 20
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:09.465495 #54236] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[805b08d0]: sent 24 bytes
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:09.465625 #54236] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[805b08d0]: received packet nr 3 type 21 len 12
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:09.466203 #54236] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[81984a3c]: beginning authentication of `ubuntu'
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:09.466417 #54236] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[805b08d0]: queueing packet nr 4 type 5 len 28
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:09.466505 #54236] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[805b08d0]: sent 52 bytes
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:09.950650 #54236] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[805b08d0]: read 52 bytes
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:09.950833 #54236] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[805b08d0]: received packet nr 4 type 6 len 28
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:09.951010 #54236] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[81984a3c]: trying none
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:09.951214 #54236] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[805b08d0]: queueing packet nr 5 type 50 len 44
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:09.951298 #54236] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[805b08d0]: sent 68 bytes
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:10.887347 #54236] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[805b08d0]: read 52 bytes
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:10.887521 #54236] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[805b08d0]: received packet nr 5 type 51 len 28
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:10.887636 #54236] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[81984a3c]: allowed methods: publickey
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:10.887720 #54236] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.methods.none[819a02a0]: none failed
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:10.887800 #54236] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[81984a3c]: trying publickey
E, [2015-01-23T16:27:10.888934 #54236] ERROR -- net.ssh.authentication.key_manager[81990d8c]: could not load public key file `/Users/antkong/dev/project/aws/ubuntu-aws-ec2-konga.pem': Net::SSH::Exception (public key at /Users/antkong/dev/project/aws/ubuntu-aws-ec2-konga.pem.pub is not valid)
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:10.889008 #54236] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[819b48b8]: connecting to ssh-agent
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:10.889130 #54236] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[819b48b8]: sending agent request 1 len 61
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:10.889217 #54236] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[819b48b8]: received agent packet 2 len 5
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:10.889260 #54236] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[819b48b8]: sending agent request 11 len 0
D, [2015-01-23T16:27:10.889317 #54236] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[819b48b8]: received agent packet 12 len 5
E, [2015-01-23T16:27:10.889359 #54236] ERROR -- net.ssh.authentication.session[81984a3c]: all authorization methods failed (tried none, publickey)

DEBUG ssh: == Net-SSH connection debug-level log END ==
 INFO ssh: SSH not up: #<Vagrant::Errors::SSHAuthenticationFailed: SSH authentication failed! This is typically caused by the public/private
keypair for the SSH user not being properly set on the guest VM. Please
verify that the guest VM is setup with the proper public key, and that
the private key path for Vagrant is setup properly as well.>
ERROR warden: Error occurred: Guest-specific operations were attempted on a machine that is not
ready for guest communication. This should not happen and a bug
should be reported.
 ...
 INFO warden: Beginning recovery process...
 INFO warden: Recovery complete.
ERROR warden: Error occurred: Guest-specific operations were attempted on a machine that is not
ready for guest communication. This should not happen and a bug
should be reported.
 INFO warden: Beginning recovery process...
 INFO warden: Recovery complete.
ERROR warden: Error occurred: Guest-specific operations were attempted on a machine that is not
ready for guest communication. This should not happen and a bug
should be reported.
 INFO warden: Beginning recovery process...
 INFO warden: Calling recover: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::Call:0x000001014851a0>
 INFO warden: Beginning recovery process...
 INFO warden: Recovery complete.
 INFO warden: Recovery complete.
 INFO warden: Beginning recovery process...
 INFO warden: Recovery complete.
 INFO warden: Beginning recovery process...
 INFO warden: Recovery complete.
 INFO warden: Beginning recovery process...
 INFO warden: Recovery complete.
 INFO warden: Beginning recovery process...
 INFO warden: Recovery complete.
 INFO warden: Beginning recovery process...
 INFO warden: Recovery complete.
 INFO environment: Released process lock: machine-action-8d4f93c9bedf41af432adedf7b959248
 INFO environment: Running hook: environment_unload
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 2 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x000001025849b0>
ERROR vagrant: Vagrant experienced an error! Details:
ERROR vagrant: #<Vagrant::Errors::MachineGuestNotReady: Guest-specific operations were attempted on a machine that is not
ready for guest communication. This should not happen and a bug
should be reported.>
ERROR vagrant: Guest-specific operations were attempted on a machine that is not
ready for guest communication. This should not happen and a bug
should be reported.
ERROR vagrant: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:231:in `guest'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/synced_folders/rsync/synced_folder.rb:31:in `enable'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folders.rb:90:in `block in call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folders.rb:87:in `each'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folders.rb:87:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/Users/antkong/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-2.0.1/lib/berkshelf/vagrant/action/upload.rb:24:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/Users/antkong/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-2.0.1/lib/berkshelf/vagrant/action/install.rb:35:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/Users/antkong/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-omnibus-1.4.1/lib/vagrant-omnibus/action/install_chef.rb:38:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:80:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/Users/antkong/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-2.0.1/lib/berkshelf/vagrant/action/configure_chef.rb:22:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/Users/antkong/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-2.0.1/lib/berkshelf/vagrant/action/load_shelf.rb:27:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/Users/antkong/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-2.0.1/lib/berkshelf/vagrant/action/set_ui.rb:11:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/env_set.rb:19:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:196:in `action_raw'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:173:in `block in action'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:474:in `lock'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:161:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:161:in `action'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/commands/provision/command.rb:30:in `block in execute'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:226:in `block in with_target_vms'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:220:in `each'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:220:in `with_target_vms'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/commands/provision/command.rb:29:in `execute'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:42:in `execute'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:292:in `cli'
/Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/bin/vagrant:174:in `<main>'
 INFO interface: error: Guest-specific operations were attempted on a machine that is not
ready for guest communication. This should not happen and a bug
should be reported.
Guest-specific operations were attempted on a machine that is not
ready for guest communication. This should not happen and a bug
should be reported.
 INFO interface: Machine: error-exit ["Vagrant::Errors::MachineGuestNotReady", "Guest-specific operations were attempted on a machine that is not\nready for guest communication. This should not happen and a bug\nshould be reported."]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out in the same location where i keep my private key, I also put the public key there

```
/Users/antkong/dev/project/aws/ubuntu-aws-ec2-konga.pem.pub
```

For some reason the  `net.ssh.authentication.key_manager` picked the public key file even though I specified the private key location.

After I remove the public key, `vagrant` can connect to the aws ec2 instance again.

Answer (score 5):

My environment is have a homestead to work with Laravel, but I'm using Vagrant Box, so I have this problem, the solution that I found was:

Works for me:

`vagrant reload --provision`

Inside the folder Homestead.